# Problem with opening local saved svf file in offline forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are converting ***rvt*** file to ***svf*** and saved it in local store.
Now we are want to open this saved file in offline viewer.
We have code for offline viewer but have problems, when we run this code with visual studio code from 'Go live server, we can see result. But when we want to run that code from server, we getting error with status 404.

here attached code and error`

[image: code]

[image: error in viewer]

[image: error in console]

Comment: please add your code with copy paste, not like an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra `../` from the beginning of model's URL  - looks like your viewer HTML is already at the root path on your server so in the screenshot you ended up with the wrong path `http://Test_2/...` for the model...